# Constant current power supply and 2 LED - series or parellel?

Tags: led, current, parallel, series

I have a very limited understanding of how current works in parallel or in series.  I am trying to connect a pair of LEDs to a constant current power supply (1200ma) in which the power supply automatically adjusts the output voltage according to the current draw.

Which (if any) will result in a brighter output?  Series or parallel configuration?

The LEDs are Cree XP-G2 1A R5 that can handle 1.5A of current.  Of course I don't want to max this out because it will create too much heat.  I have tried both setups and measured the amp draw maxed at 1200ma but I can't tell which is brighter.  Does it even matter in my case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should connect them in series because:

- if diodes are connected in series - exactly the same current is flowing
- current will be 1200mA, because it does not split like in parallel

[image]

In series - circuit will need higher voltage to reach 1200mA on these leds, because in series voltage (not current) splits.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Series connected since power supply voltage is adjustable but current source has 1200 mA limit. To draw current required by two series connected LED voltage needs to be increased.